# Using MS Access SQL, How Do I Delete Rows With Duplicate Values In Only One Column?

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

Using MS Access SQL, I am trying to figure out how to delete rows with *duplicate values in one column*.

**Example Data:**

```
Department      | Job Category        | Name | Requestor ID
Medical Affairs | Vice President      | Kim  | 123
Medical Affairs | President           | Abe  | 123
Nursing         | Sr Vice President   | Bob  | 456
Nursing         | Exec Vice President | Jim  | 456
Patient Care    | President           | Sam  | 456
```

In the example above, I want to delete the rows with duplicate **Requestor ID** to only leave the row with the lowest **Job Category** (even if the **Job Category** is in different **Department**s). That means I would only be left with these rows below when I'm done deleting my duplicates:

**Results:**

```
Department      | Job Category        | Name | Requestor ID
Medical Affairs | Vice President      | Kim  | 123
Nursing         | Sr Vice President   | Bob  | 456
```

I am pretty new to MS Access SQL so I don't even know where to start. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Is there any logic around which department or category should be removed vs kept?

Comment: Ideally you would create a rank table which outlines the Job Category and which is highest.   Once you have this you can link the tables, sort them accordingly and deal with the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what the "lowest" job category is?

Well, you can do something like this:

```
select e.*
from example as e
where e.jobcategory <> (select top (1) e2.jobcategory
                        from example e2
                        where e2.requestorid = e.requestorid
                        order by switch(jobcategory = 'President', 1,
                                        jobcategory = 'Exec Vice President', 2,
                                        jobcategory = 'Sr Vice President', 3,
                                        jobcategory = 'Vice President', 4,
                                        ) desc
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I could get the results that I wanted by constructing the code below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS a 
RIGHT JOIN TableB AS b 
ON a.[Requestor ID] = b.[Requestor ID] 
WHERE a.[Requestor ID] IS NULL
```

By using this code, I will get unique **Requestor ID**s and will not run into the issue of having duplicate **Requestor ID**s with different **Departments**, **Job Categories** and **Names**.

The code below caused the issue I was facing, whereby I got duplicate **Requestor ID**s with different **Departments**, **Job Categories** and **Names** since I was unable to filter out rows with **Requestor IDs** that were already in my original table (**TableA**).

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA

UNION

SELECT *
FROM TableB
```

Thanks, everyone, for your help!